# show Distance within particular kilometers in the selected city

Tags: codeigniter

I need to do a new task in codeigniter , i have a project for bus travels. according to booking like bangalore to delhi,raipur to bilaspur i have to calculate distance.and show its in kilometer.he front end if the user enter the city source and destination and it will be calculate automatically.Anyone know if this can be accomplish? As I desperately need some help. Thanks in advance!

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

```
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
    ?>
```

i tried this thing but its fine.according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path in a graph. You cannot assume that the paths are straight lines as if you were flying. You need to have a matrix containing the distances between cities.

Comment: Do you mean "is it" or "it is" possible? Are you asking a question?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/ on how to call Google Maps API

Comment: I think that using Google Maps API is better than reinventing the wheel. However, you need to ensure that Google terms of service will not cause you trouble.